# How to zip git branch?

Tags: git, command-line, zip, compression, archive

I understand that this will zip my latest commit:

```
git archive -o latest.zip HEAD
```

However, I want to zip ALL my commits in my local repository, so my colleague can traverse my commits and see different versions of my code. I want to contain the complete history of git commits.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git archive is used for exporting a git repository and removes all git related information.

Probably [git bundle](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-bundle.html) is the command you are looking for.
This works fine if you just want to share your repository with your colleague, so he can have a look at it.
If you are working on the same project and both of you need to make changes, using a [remote](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) might be a better way to share your repository.